# Calling a function while angular gives error 'net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I loose net connection and try to load a HTML template(which is not loaded previously) using angularJS it gives me error, `net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`.

Is there any way to call a function before angular fires error `net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED` , so I will be able to notify user they have lost their connection.

I don't want to put watchers on online/offline status since I want user to be able to see previously loaded HTML templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From angularjs docs

```js
angular.module('exceptionOverride', []).factory('$exceptionHandler', function() {
  return function(exception, cause) {
    exception.message += ' (caused by "' + cause + '")';
    throw exception;
  };
});
```

Use this to catch every exception, including internet connection problems, it all runs through this method

Comment: can you give a example for this.

Comment: "net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED" is chrome error, not angular as far as I remember. Insert into method i posted some "online-check", an ajax request for example or "navigator.onLine" condition. You can detect if internet connection has gone down, but I am not sure if you can prevent error from appearing

Comment: I don't want to prevent the error. I just want to know if the template is going to loaded or not. If not I will show something to user. Like I said in the question itself I don't want to do that on the basis of internet connection as user should be able to see the pages which are in the cache.